# Why did Eternity, Infinity or the Living Tribunal not intervene with Sise-neg's manipulations of time?

Tags: marvel, comics, doctor-strange

In one of the Doctor Strange comics (someone remind me which one it was...) we find that Cagliostro's book about time manipulation, or more accurately, manipulation of the past without changing the present, has fallen into the hands of the Baron and Dr. Strange then goes back in time to meet Cagliostro who in turn tells him that he actually is a time-travelling magician(?) from the future and wishes to alter the past and become God, which he eventually succeeds in becoming.

What I did not understand was, how was that not taken notice of by any of the Eternal Cosmic Beings. This surely couldn't have been beneath their notice. Or did Sise-neg somehow escape their detection?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're referring to *[Marvel Premiere #13](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Premiere_Vol_1_13)* & *[14](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Premiere_Vol_1_14)*, primarily the latter issue, in which [Sise-Neg](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Sise-Neg_(Earth-74113)) travels back to the beginning of time and becomes powerful enough to recreate (or create?) the universe.

It's tricky to say exactly why Eternity, Infinity, or the Living Tribunal didn't intervene with Sise-Neg's actions, because we don't see much of these beings, or know much about the way they think. It's a bit like trying to peer into the mind of God (if there is a God). A couple of possibilities spring to mind though.

Firstly, the story ends on an ambiguous note. Sise-Neg travels back to the black void that existed before the Big Bang in the Marvel Universe, with Dr. Strange and Baron Mordo following him there. At that point, Sise-Neg has attained a God-like state of existence, and comes to the conclusion that he couldn't improve upon the universe as it'd already existed, so he recreates it exactly as it was, triggering a (the?) Big Bang event. Strange and Mordo are sent back to their own time, and Strange is left to wonder whether he just witnessed the universe being recreated, or whether that's how it was created all along. If we go with the latter interpretation, then by not interfering, Eternity, Infinity, and the Living Tribunal were simply allowing history to unfold in the same way that it always had.

> DR. STRANGE: We're back! Mordo, we're back! --And everything appears to be as it was--Mordo? By the Hoary Hosts of Hoggoth! He is stupefied! **He witnessed the second creation of the universe--and the sight was too much for him! But--did we see the second creation--or could it have been the first, reoccurring? Einstein believed that if you launched yourself into space, you would eventually come back upon yourself! Perhaps time is similar. Perhaps the end of our journey had to be the beginning!**
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Marvel Premiere #14* (March, 1974)</sub>

Furthermore, according to their entries in *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_4)* and *[5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A_to_Z_Vol_1_5)*, Eternity and Infinity were brought into existence by the Big Bang, so why would they want to interfere in their own creation?

> Eternity came into existence when the universe was born, and has referred to many of the other abstract beings who came into existence with it as both siblings and offspring.
>
> *Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #4* (September, 2008)

> Infinity was 'born', along with the other abstracts, with the 'Big Bang'.
>
> *Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z #5* (November, 2008)

Secondly, even if we assume that Sise-Neg did technically alter the timeline -- in that he wasn't originally the source of the Big Bang -- ultimately, whatever change he made was of little or no practical consequence, since the universe was apparently recreated exactly as it was. Perhaps Eternity, Infinity, and the Living Tribunal knew this, and therefore didn't see anything to be gained by intervening. Does it really matter who or what creates the universe, if it turns out the same, regardless?

Suggesting that they knew the universe was going to turn out the same is speculative, of course, but then again, suggesting that they *didn't* know would be equally speculative. As I indicated near the beginning of this answer, we just don't know enough about these beings to be sure how their minds work, or whether they were or weren't aware of how things were going to turn out in that story.

Comment: I just remembered that Doctor Strange ponders this very question somewhere in the same comic. On a side note, are we allowed to post pictures of the pages of comic books? Does that not give rise to copyright or other similar issues?

Comment: Also, when Doctor Strange encounters Cagliostro for the first time, was it really him or, as we later see, Doctor Strange meeting his past self? As in, was that the first iteration of the loop or just one in many such?